# What is the difference between String arrays created in xml and one initialized in Java class

Tags: java, android, xml, string

Is there any differences between creating a string array in the strings xml file

```
<string-array name="stringName">
     <item>Item1</item>
     <item>Item2</item>
</string-array>
```

and initiliazing it in Java

```
String stringName[]={"Item1","Item2"};
```

Comment: What sort of differences are you thinking of? There may be differences in terms of whether the strings themselves are inlined... but in both cases you'll just get an array of two elements...

Comment: String resource array can be access globally in application and constants are compiled into the java bytecode; project resources are compiled into a binary format within the apk. Accessing either is extremely efficient... if there is a difference between the two, it is trivial at most..

Comment: Is there a situation when I should use one over the other. Are there some things you can do with strings initialized in Java that you can't do with strings created in xml? I've been going through some tutorials and I noticed some of them create the strings in java and some in the strings xml file.

Comment: @AdamV,Which aproach you have to use it's depend upon on ur requirement if you required string array many place in your application then you have to define in string resource one time and access over application any where if you just required in one place then try to define on that place only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that strings defined as `string-array` can be easily localized:

```
<string-array name="stringName">
     <item>@string/item1</item>
     <item>@string/item2</item>
</string-array>
```

Thus, if you want them to be translated, it's a good idea to put them into resources.

Answer (score 1):

The one difference I can think of is that the Strings declared in code (i.e. `String stringName[]={"Item1","Item2"};`) are interned, as such the following code will evaluate to *true*:

```
String s1="this is a string";
String s2="this is a string";
if(s1==s2) {
   ...
}
```

However for Strings created from, say, XML, two String Objects will not have the same identity and will therefore the "==" operator will evaluate to *false* even when the actual value contained in the two Strings are the same. This holds true until `String.intern()` is used, after which "==" evaluation of two String Objects of the same value will evaluate true again.

The code below demonstrate the difference:

```
    String s1[] = { "Item1", "Item2" };
    String s2[] = { "Item1", "Item2" };
    //true
    System.out.println("Test.main: " + (s1[0] == s2[0]));

    s1 = new String[] { new String("Item1"), new String("Item2") };
    s2 = new String[] { new String("Item1"), new String("Item2") };
    //false
    System.out.println("Test.main: " + (s1[0] == s2[0]));

    s1 = new String[] { new String("Item1").intern(), new String("Item2") };
    s2 = new String[] { new String("Item1").intern(), new String("Item2") };
    //true
    System.out.println("Test.main: " + (s1[0] == s2[0]));
```

Comment: Adding to Kai's answer, there might be a difference in the number of string objects that are created for repeating values. If the same `item` repeats again in the XML, then a new string object is created again for that where as all strings literals that can be resolved at compile time are interned implicitly, so even in case of `String a = "item1"` and somewhere else in code if there's a `String b = "item1"`, only 1 string object is created.

Answer (score 0):

To retrive a `string-array`:

```
<string-array name="stringName">
  <item>Item1</item>
  <item>Item2</item>
</string-array>

Resources res = getResources();
String[] stringName = res.getStringArray(R.array.stringName);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array or anything else in the resources (XML), they are stored as your app's resources in the APK file, but not in the code. If you make excessive use of resources in XML, it can increase the size of your APK. Of course, making a presentation in resources makes it easier to access them. If you need an array many times in your application, it is better to use the XML array. But if you need an array only once or twice, it is better to
create and initial it in Java or Kotlin code.